# Re-sign IPA exported with export_method "app-store" with an adhoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I'm using fastlane to create an IPA file using

```
build_app(export_method: "app-store",scheme: "my-scheme",clean: true)
```

I can upload this to the app store just fine. What I'm trying to do after is (without rebuilding/reexporting the IPA using `export_method: ad-hoc`) to distribute this same built IPA using an adhoc provisiong profile instead of an app-store profile

```
resign(
        ipa: "fastlane/build/app.ipa",
        signing_identity: "Apple Distribution: Blah (1234)",
        display_name: "new name Beta",
        short_version: current_version + "-beta"
    )
```

However, when i try to install the re-signed ipa, i get

> this app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified

I tried building a brand new IPA using that same provisioning profile but with the proper export_method ad-hoc and this works, so I know the PP works fine. This means that the problem really is with the re-signing

Is this combination of exporting using method `app-store` and then re-signing it with an ad-hoc provisioning profile just not possible?

My build is very slow, so i'm trying to take advantage of the existing IPA instead of creating a new one for a beta build